# Changing HTML attribute with URL

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, attributes, elementor

I'm not entirely sure if this is possible and have been unable to find any info on this matter, which isn't giving me much hope, but maybe I can find an answer this way. For some context, my question concerns [this page](https://zonnescholen.nl/aanpak/). For reference: I'll be referring to "tabs" in my question, this is about the tabs towards the bottom of that page, not browser tabs.

I'm working on a revamp of the website for the company I work for as a Communications employee. As part of this revamp, we want to place an infographic on the website detailing our work process, and allow users to click it to get information about the step of the infographic they just clicked on. We use Wordpress and a free version of Elementor, which limits my ability to make any changes outside of the front-end that Wordpress/Elementor gives me.

I'm currently using Adobe Illustrator to create an image map of the infographic using Illustrator's Attributes menu, and have been able to use hash signs to make the page jump down to the text about the step by using the `div id` of the tab in question. However, in order to make this work, I also need to be able to actually change the open tab on the page. I've figured out that this relies on two HTML attributes needing to be changed:

- The `class` attribute of both the tab that needs to close and the tab that needs to be opened needs to be adjusted. A closed tab uses `elementor-tab-title elementor-tab-desktop-title`, an open tab uses `elementor-tab-title elementor-tab-desktop-title elementor-active`.
- The `aria-expanded` attribute of the tab that needs to close needs to be changed to `false`, while the tab that needs to be opened requries the attribute to be set to `true`.

Is there any way to pull this off using the URL? If not, what other methods can I use, given the limitations of the system I'm working with?

I've searched across the internet for solutions, taken a look at Elementor-focused tutorials, and searched Stack Exchange. While I have found solutions that involve JS/JQuery scripting, this is unfortunately not possible due to the limitations of the software I'm working with. If there's something that involves a URL, I can use that through image mapping, which should allow me to work around these limitations.

Comment: If you want to handle this using url, you need to use PHP or Javascript - and the most simple way is use the Elementor HTML widget and add your JS/Jquery script there.

Comment: Hi, could you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: what sort of editing capabilities do you have for the tabs?

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand your question. So, do you want to redirect via url to a different tab and close the one (eventually) already open?

Comment: Why does using Elementor and WordPress limit your ability to use Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You question is not entirely clear on what you expect the URL to look like.

Or how you expect to change the URL.

But you can surely change the elements on the front-end page based on the URL.

For example like this:

```js
// get and parse url parameters
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

// extract the ones you are interested in
let currentTabID = urlParams.get('currentTab');
let closedTabID = urlParams.get('closedTab');

// since you don't specify what sets the URL I suppose it will be blank by default 
// and only be filled on page visit. So lets set the default
currentTabID = currentTabID || 'home';

// get the tab HTML elements
// Note: the usage of $ prefix on elements is just a naming habit from jQuery and not mandatory
let $closedTab = document.getElementById(closedTabID);
let $currentTab = document.getElementById(currentTabID);

// change their classes or whatver else you need to
if($closedTab) $closedTab.addClass('tab-closing');
if($currentTab) $currentTab.addClass('tab-selected');
```

This would work for an URL matching:
`https://example.com?currentTab=about&closedTab=contacts`

You will likely want to set the URL parameters on each tab link.
To change the URL when the user clicks the tab link.

```html
<a class='tab'href="?currentTab=about">About us</a>
```

This will however not include the closed tab in the URL, you need to do that through Javascript:

```js
 //continuing from the above script where we captured the urlParams

document.getElementsByClassName('tab').forEach(($element)=>{
  $element.href = $element.href + '&closedTab=' + currentTab
})
```